# AddressSanitizer not finding an obvious leak after changing printf

Tags: c, memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

I'm scratching my head trying to figure out why ASAN isn't picking up on a simple memory leak. valgrind finds it just fine. Help?

Example that ASAN *does* find.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void blah(void)
{
        int *some_int = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *some_int = 1;
        printf("hello %p\n", some_int);
        // some_int is lost here
}

int main()
{
        blah();
        return 0;
}

mbryan@remotedev-mbryan:~/git/mbryan/onefs$ clang -fsanitize=address -O0 q.c
mbryan@remotedev-mbryan:~/git/mbryan/onefs$ ./a.out
hello 0x602000000010

=================================================================
==10751==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 4 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x4d9bd0 in malloc (/ifs/home/mbryan/git/mbryan/onefs/a.out+0x4d9bd0)
    #1 0x5120f3 in blah (/ifs/home/mbryan/git/mbryan/onefs/a.out+0x5120f3)
    #2 0x512183 in main (/ifs/home/mbryan/git/mbryan/onefs/a.out+0x512183)
    #3 0x7f3515000b96 in __libc_start_main /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/csu/../csu/libc-start.c:310

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 4 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

So far so good. Now print the value instead of the pointer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void blah(void)
{
        int *some_int = malloc(sizeof(int));
        *some_int = 1;
        printf("hello %d\n", *some_int);  // <---------------
}

int main()
{
        blah();
        return 0;
}

mbryan@remotedev-mbryan:~/git/mbryan/onefs$ clang -fsanitize=address -O0 q.c
mbryan@remotedev-mbryan:~/git/mbryan/onefs$ ./a.out
hello 1
```

...now the leak doesn't show up.

On the latter if I recompile without the sanitizer and run valgrind, valgrind does indeed show a leak:
==10782==    definitely lost: 4 bytes in 1 blocks

Looking at the assembly: I see the optimimzer hasn't made my malloc'd variable a local or some other trickery. So: why isn't AddressSanitizer picking up this one?  Am I missing something obvious?

This is on Ubuntu18.04 using clang 6.0.0-1ubuntu2.

Comment: FWIW, when I try this on my CentOS 7.7 system with clang 3.4.2, it reports no memory issues for either one.

Comment: @Steve Did you set ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1? Apparently lsan is off by default. https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizerLeakSanitizer

Comment: This is the first time I've ever used clang, but trying it again as you suggested reveals the same behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been informed from the ASAN folks that this is a known bug:
https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/937

LeakSanitizer: false negative when functions stack frames overlay #937

Comment: Yeah; SO makes me wait at least 5 hours to do it, hehe. I don't know why.